# Modifying axes properties in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know why depending on how you call `plt.plot()` on an `ax` this `ax` may or may not be able to be modified downstream. Is this a bug in `matplotlib` or am I misunderstanding something? An example which illustrates the issue is shown below.

I am attempting to modify the legend location downstream of a plotting function call, similar to as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4701285/1451311). For whatever reason this seams to be dependent on how I call `ax.plot`. Here are two examples illustrating the issue

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myplot(df, ax, loop_cols):
    if loop_cols:
        for col in df.columns:
            ax.plot(df.loc[:, col])
    else:
        ax.plot(df)
    ax.legend(df.columns)
    return ax
```

This just amounts to calling `ax.plot()` repeatedly on the `pd.Series`, or calling it once on the `pd.DataFrame`. However depending on how this is called, it results in the inability to later modify the legend, as shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3)).cumsum()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
myplot(df, ax, loop_cols=True)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Chart legend properly set to right side

[image]

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
myplot(df, ax, loop_cols=False)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Chart legend not set to appropriate location

[image]

This is with `matplotlib` version `2.1.0`

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using pandas `DataFrame.plot()`?

Comment: For this toy example that may be the best option, but the module I'm using this in attempts to use `ax.plot()` to be consistent throughout, since I seem to recall various differences in behaviour related to formatting for `DataFrame.plot` vs `ax.plot`

Comment: Fair enough. What version of matplotlib are you using? No legend appears for me when `loop_cols=False` using `matplotlib 2.1.2`

Comment: Edited the answer to include the version

Answer (score 0):

I'm not why this behaviour is actually happening.... but you are calling `ax.legend` twice, once in the function, and once outside it. Altering your function such that the call to `ax.legend()` inside the function contains all the information solves the problem. This includes passing the legend handles and labels. In the example below I used `ax.lines` to get the `Line2D` objects, however if your plots are more complicated you may have to get the list from the call to plot using `lines = ax.plot()`

If the properties of the legend change then you could modify the function to accept paramters that are passed to `ax.legend`.

```
def myplot(df, ax, loop_cols):
    if loop_cols:
        for col in df.columns:
            ax.plot(df.loc[:, col])    
    else:
        ax.plot(df)
    #ax.legend(df.columns)  # modify this line
    ax.legend(ax.lines, df.columns, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
    return ax

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(6,4))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3)).cumsum()

myplot(df, ax, loop_cols=True)
ax.set_title("loop_cols=True")
#ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))  # No need for this

myplot(df, ax2, loop_cols=False)
ax2.set_title("loop_cols=False")
#ax2.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))  # No need for this

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08,right=0.88,wspace=0.55)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the work around, but my main issue is that I would like to write the function in a way such that a user can overwrite the default behaviour if they want. While for this case I could expose this as an extra function parameter, tweaking the various properties of an `ax` is quite a large API and thus I would like to be able to return an `ax` that the user can modify. The true goal was somewhat ambiguous in my question, I have edited it to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Legends are not being modified in the above examples, new legends are being created in both cases. The issue relates to how `legend()` behaves differently depending on if there are labels on the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`s. The relevant section from the docs is

> **1. Automatic detection of elements to be shown in the legend**
>
> The elements to be added to the legend are automatically determined,
>   when you do not pass in any extra arguments.
>
> In this case, the labels are taken from the artist. You can specify
>   them either at artist creation or by calling the
>   :meth:`~.Artist.set_label` method on the artist::
>
> ```
> line, = ax.plot([1, 2, 3], label='Inline label')
> ax.legend()
> ```
>
> or::
>
> ```
> line.set_label('Label via method')
> line, = ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
> ax.legend()
> ```
>
> Specific lines can be excluded from the automatic legend element
>   selection by defining a label starting with an underscore. This is
>   default for all artists, so calling `Axes.legend` without any
>   arguments and without setting the labels manually will result in no
>   legend being drawn.
>
> **2. Labeling existing plot elements**
>
> To make a legend for lines which already exist on the axes (via plot
>   for instance), simply call this function with an iterable of strings,
>   one for each legend item. For example::
>
> ```
> ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
> ax.legend(['A simple line'])
> ```
>
> Note: This way of using is discouraged, because the relation between
>   plot elements and labels is only implicit by their order and can
>   easily be mixed up.

In the first case, no labels are set

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 5, 3], 'b': [1, 3, -4]})
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1)
lines = axes.plot(df)
print(lines[0].get_label())
print(lines[1].get_label())

_line0
_line1
```

So calling `legend()` the first time with labels falls under case **2.**. When `legend` is called the second time without labels it falls under case **1.** As you can see, the `Legend` instances are different, and the second one rightly complains there are `No handles with labels found to put in legend.`

```
l1 = axes.legend(['a', 'b'])
print(repr(l1))
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x7f05638b7748>

l2 = axes.legend(loc='upper left')
No handles with labels found to put in legend.
print(repr(l2))
<matplotlib.legend.Legend object at 0x7f05638004e0>
```

In the second case, the lines are properly labelled and therefore the second call to `legend()` properly infers the labels.

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name='a')
s2 = pd.Series([1, 5, 2], name='b')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1)
line1 = axes.plot(s1)
line2 = axes.plot(s2)
print(line1[0].get_label())
print(line2[0].get_label())

a
b
```